# Multi-type allocator design

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on the runtime library for a dynamic language, and more specifically on its memory allocation.

I will use garbage collection, but I thought it would be nice to allow the user to use its own memory allocator if it needs to. However, after looking at the [standard c++ allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) interface, I didn't seen any way to have a generic allocator (except by templating on char, but it seems hacky).

- Is it a good idea to use the standard allocator interface ?
- If it is, what would be a possible design for allocating multiple types ?

Note : My library use C++11, so I'm talking about the 'new' allocator interface.

Comment: Are you looking for `allocator::rebind`? I updated the [cppreference page you link to](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) to explain a little bit about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Cubbi said, look at `allocator::rebind`. The actual type argument to an allocator is pretty-much irrelevant. Standard containers use `allocator::rebind` to change to the type that they actually need. In particular, associative containers need to allocate nodes that hold their own data as well as the data objects that the container nominally holds. So `allocator::rebind` is used to get an `allocator<Node<T>>` from an `allocator<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether you want compile-time or run-time polymorphism. The standard allocator is good for the former case. For the latter, you can do something like:

```
class Allocator {
public:
    virtual void* allocate(std::size_t size) = 0;
    virtual void deallocate(void* p) = 0;
}
```

The users would be able to customize the allocator via the virtual functions.